# Groupby in pandas multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame called `bf`. The commas are mine, it was imported from a csv file.

```
val,ben
a,123
b,234
c,123
```

I have another larger data frame `df`

```
    bla,val, blablab, blablaa
    1,a,123,333
    2,b,333,222
    3,c,12,33
    1,a,123,333
    .....
```

I would like to create a new data frame which multiplies all rows of  `df` with the specific value corresponding to `ben` for it, taken from `bf`. For exaple the first row of this new data frame will be `1,a,123*123,333*123` How do we do that using pandas and groupby?

EDIT: Note that `bf` and `df` have different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to use a merge to bring in the column `ben` into your dataframe:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df, bf, on='val')
```

Then you can calculate your product however you like, for example:

```
df_prod = df_merged * df_merged.ben
```

Comment: you need to `import pandas as pd`, (you'll find as you read more pandas code that this is standard usage)

Comment: although you can also use the syntax `df_merged = df.merge(bf, on='val)`